# How to force initState every time the page is rendered in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget, flutter-state

I am adding some data into the `SharedPreferences`on page2 of my app and I am trying to retrieve the data on the homepage. I have used an init function on page 1 as follows:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    

    _getrecent();
  }

  void _getrecent() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // prefs.clear();
    String b = prefs.getString("recent").toString();
    Map<String, dynamic> p = json.decode(b);

    if (b.isNotEmpty) {
      print("Shared pref:" + b);
      setState(() {
        c = Drug.fromJson(p);
      });
      cond = true;
    } else {
      print("none in shared prefs");
      cond = false;
    }
  }
```

Since the `initState()` loads only once, I was wondering if there was a way to load it every time page1 is rendered. Or perhaps there is a better way to do this. I am new to flutter so I don't have a lot of idea in State Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First thing is you can't force `initState` to rebuild your widget.
> For that you have `setState` to rebuild your widget. As far as I can
> understand you want to recall `initState` just to call `_getrecent()`
> again.

**Here's what you should ideally do :**

A simple solution would be to use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). You just need to use `_getrecent()` in `FutureBuilder` as parent where you want to use the data you get from `_getrecent()`. This way everytime your `Widget` rebuilds it will call `_getrecent()`.

Comment: Should I change the return type of `_getrecent()` to something other than `void` ?

Comment: As I can see in the code you shared that you're using `c = Drug.fromJson(p);` value somewhere in your widget. Ideally you should return this value and wrap `FutureBuilder` to the widget which needs this value.

Answer (score 1):

you can override `didChangeDependencies` method. Called when a dependency of the [State] object changes as you use the `setState`,

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
// your codes
}
```

Also, you should know that using `setState` updates the whole widget, which has an overhead. To avoid that you should `const`, declaring a widget const will only render once so it's efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You simply use `setState()` methode if you want to update widget. Here's documentation for this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Answer (score 0):

`init function` will render it only once initially, to avoid that -

You can use `setState( )` method to re-render your whole widget.